# MySQL Statement Return Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql

I'm working ob Report about Cashiers I want in this report know total of cashier in specific day and I wrote SQL Statement but this statement Return Duplicate Row ..it's Repeat Records when I make left join with tables. This my SQL statement:

```
select DISTINCT
tblcashiers.CashierName,
IFNULL(tblcashieropeningbalance.Mount, 0) as COB,
IFNULL(tblcashdeposit.Mount, 0) as CD,
IFNULL(tblbankcashiertransfer.Mount, 0) as BCT,
IFNULL(tblsupplierrefund.Refund, 0) as SPR ,
IFNULL(tblcustomrefund.Refund , 0) as CUR,
IFNULL(tblcashpayments.Mount, 0) as CP,
IFNULL(tblcashiertransfer.Mount, 0) as CT,
IFNULL(tblcashiertransfer.Mount, 0) as CT2,
IFNULL(tblcustomerrefund.Refund, 0) as CR,
IFNULL(tblcashierbanktransfer.Mount, 0)as CBT,
IFNULL(tblexpenses.Mount, 0)as EX,
IFNULL(tblcustomespayment.Mount, 0)as CUSP

from tblcashiers
LEFT  JOIN tblcashdeposit on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashdeposit.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblbankcashiertransfer on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblbankcashiertransfer.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblsupplierrefund  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblsupplierrefund.CashierID  
LEFT  JOIN tblcustomrefund  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcustomrefund.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblcashpayments  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashpayments.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblcustomerrefund  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcustomerrefund.CashierID ='2'
LEFT  JOIN tblcashierbanktransfer  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashierbanktransfer.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblcashiertransfer  on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashiertransfer.FromCashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblcashiertransfer as tblcashiertransfer2 on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashiertransfer2.ToCashierID 
-- LEFT JOIN tblcashiers as tblcashiers on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashiers.CashierID
 LEFT JOIN tblcashieropeningbalance on tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID = tblcashiers.CashierID 
LEFT JOIN tblexpenses as tblexpenses on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblexpenses.CashierID 
LEFT  JOIN tblcustomespayment as tblcustomespayment on tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcustomespayment.CashierID 
 where tblcashiers.CashierID = 2 

and tblcashdeposit .TransDate >= '2016-01-01'
and tblcashdeposit .TransDate <= '2016-03-01'

GROUP BY tblcashieropeningbalance.TransDate,
tblcashdeposit.TransDate,   tblbankcashiertransfer.TransDate,
tblsupplierrefund.RefundDate,   tblcashpayments.TransDate,  
tblcustomerrefund.RefundDate,  tblcashierbanktransfer.TransDate,
tblcashiertransfer.TransDate,  tblcashiertransfer.TransDate,
tblexpenses.TransDate,tblcustomespayment.TransDate
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the GROUP BY from the query. GROUP BY is only used if you mix normal columns with aggregate functions in SELECT. Your query does not contain any aggregate functions (min, max...) so you do not need the GROUP BY.